# How to use one component into another component?

Tags: angularjs

I have to include a component into another component in angular 1.5. I added the component into the html, but can't resolve the js dependency. It is something with the bindings, can you give me some ideas

Comment: I have 2 ready components and just include the one into the another, but I'm missing the part with communication of the components. I'm not front end

Comment: No code, no help. Sorry. Please show us your components code as well as how you try to pass the bindings.